# Rails how to save and set time zone then find the current date for each user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a Rails 4 app I want to use a function like this

```
@bill.trading_date = 6.hours.ago.to_date
```

to set the trading date for each user. Here are the steps I want to use.

1. I want to collect and save each users time zone to a database using something like time_zone_select.
2. I want to use the saved time zone to set the current DateTime for each user.
3. I want to set a trading date using the above function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@bill.trading_date = 6.hours.ago.in_time_zone(<your time zone>).to_date
```